# How to get array of values in Excel?

Tags: excel

This may be asked before, but I was unable to locate any.

I'm having a pivot table in Excel file, with two data fields in Rows and a Value field.

Rows -> Country, Product
Values -> Sum of Amount

The data appears like below:

| Country | Products | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| France | phone | 1000 |
| Franc | earpod | 500 |
| France | mouse | 150 |
| Canada | phone | 1000 |
| Canada | chip | 500 |
| Canada | keypad | 150 |

I added a dropdown on another sheet for Country names.
I want to show a product snapshot (product names and their amount) when a country is selected.

Dropdown -> France
Snapshot

| Product | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| phone | 1000 |
| earpod | 500 |
| mouse | 150 |

Dropdown -> Canada
Snapshot

| Product | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| phone | 1000 |
| chip | 500 |
| keypad | 150 |

Can anyone please suggest what could be the EXCEL Formula (or expression) to fetch this array of values?

I tried Index and match but it failed because France is at multiple indices.

Comment: Why not just use a Slicer on the Pivot Table instead of a dropdown?

Comment: You could use the FILTER-function on the base data ...

Comment: So instead of index with match, what about sumifs()?

Comment: What version are using?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FILTER()` function like-

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:C,Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!A1)
```

If you are not using recent versions of Excel then you have to use `AGGREGATE()` function.